# Autofac - (Global) Handler/Middleware to unwrap exceptions

Tags: autofac

We would like to add a handler/middleware to Autofac to essentially unwrap any Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException; to throw the inner exception.

Hooking the Activation (or RegistrationPipelineStart) Pipeline phases (using the following code) unwraps one of the exceptions, but the exception ultimately get wrapped by another DependencyResolutionException.

```
container.RegisterServiceMiddleware<IOController>(PipelinePhase.ResolveRequestStart, (context, next) =>
{
    try
    {
        next(context);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // This unwraps one exception, but even if this is done another exception is wrapped.
        // If the inner exception is not thrown, there is a DependencyResolutionException wrapped in another DependencyResolutionException
        throw ex.InnerException;
    }
});
```

Irrespective of the phase, I always end up with the exception being wrapped.

I think I need to override the behaviour of ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware, but I cannot see a way to do this.

(I understand that Constructors should be lightweight an not throw exceptions, but we have a very large application, and are in the process of refactoring the internals...this will take several versions/iterations, so not really a possibility).

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you hoping to *catch* this exception? Around a call to `ILifetimeScope.Resolve`? Or somewhere else?

Comment: Further up the stack. Ultimately, we have existing handlers which catch, wrap and add additional messaging to the exceptions, where they are propagated either to the UI or logged.

The DependencyResolutionException(s) are just noise, and we were hoping that if we could write some middleware to unwrap the exception then we wouldn't need additional handlers at the points where exceptions in the constructors can be thrown.

Comment: OK, so the short answer to your question then really is, you can't. Any exceptions that occur inside an Autofac Resolve operation, excluding `ObjectDisposedException`, are wrapped in a `DependencyResolutionException`, to give a consistent exception surface for exceptions thrown inside constructors.  If you want to unwrap the exception, you will need to do it *outside* Autofac core functionality. Are you using one of our integrations?

Comment: @AlistairEvans Thanks for the swift reply. After doing quite a bit of research ( & testing) we thought this might be the case, so thanks for confirming. Integration - This is a large application where the exceptions can occur in numerous executable contexts (WCF Self Hosted, .exe, ASP.Net WebAPI)...so we've written our own wiring. Autofac is a great product btw.